# Can you install .NET 4.5 on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, .net-4.6, .net-4.5.2

I'm trying to setup an app on an Azure instance that another developer created.

I'm trying to user a service that looks like it requires .NET 4.5 and is not compatible with 4.6... for some reason.

The instance he setup is on Windows Server 2016, which has .NET 4.6 installed by default.

The last server I setup was 2012.

Has anyone setup .NET 4.5 on Windows Server 2016?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a cut and paste answer but this [MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-10) indicates that you can run any .NET 4.x application with higher versions of the 4.x framework.

NET Framework 4.x versions are in-place updates to earlier versions. That means the following:

- You can only have one version of the .NET Framework 4.x installed on
  your machine.
- You cannot install an earlier version of the .NET Framework on your
  machine if a later version is already installed.
- 4.x versions of the .NET Framework can be used to run applications built for the .NET Framework 4.0 through that version.    For
  example, .NET Framework 4.8 can be used to run applications built
  for the .NET Framework 4.0 through 4.8. **The latest version (.NET
  Framework 4.8) can be used to run applications built will all versions of the .NET Framework starting with 4.0.**

One thing to consider: although .NET 4.6 is installed by default, ASP.NET 4.6 is not, and you may need to add that under Features.

To modify the version of .NET, go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off. This will open the Add Roles and Features Wizard as part of Server Manager.  You can modify the .NET version during the Features step of the Wizard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can uninstall .NET Framework 4.6.1 by going to Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > View Installed Updates. Search for or scroll down the list of Microsoft Windows updates to find Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3102467) and click Uninstall.

Comment: KB3102467 seems to be the update for Windows Server 2012, not Windows Server 2016.